# Selenium: Not Finding Element/No Input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue that is intermittent. I have noticed it about 40-50% of the time with this specific website. I am clueless as to why this is occurring. It is not linked to any specific browser. It happens with both firefox and chrome.

It was not happening before...

```
browser.get("https://www.voilanorbert.com")
inputName = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-name")))
inputName.click()
inputName.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
inputDomain  = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-domain")))
inputDomain.click()
inputDomain.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i,2))
norbertsearch = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
norbertsearch.click()
```

The code above is supposed to input names from an excel sheet and domain names from this excel sheet to the corresponding boxes. However, for whatever reason, on occassion this process gets hung up on selecting the domain box.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image]

Usually there is no red box around the "@" sign in between. The process gets held up on inputting values to that box...and just times out.

So by hanging up, I mean it doesn't actually find the "domain" element. Thus, it doesn't input anything into the domain box, holding up the whole automation process and throws this exception: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: after the click dont put the input verify that the element you want to put the input is there (use your wait until)

Comment: you click on inputName before entering the domain? that seems wrong?

Comment: @Dude I made a mistake when posting the code...I click on inputDomain not inputName

Comment: hmm in java there is a expected Condition so that the element is clickable, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The only good solution I have found to this problem is execute  a javascript to set values.

```
        WebElement element = idriver.findElement(By.id(("form-search-domain")));

    ((JavascriptExecutor)idriver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'sample';", element);
```

Sorry the code sample is in Java. But all you have to do is execute javaScript 
document.findElementbyId("ID").value = "your value"

Comment: Im a little confused. My value is a local variable called domain. So I would do the following presumably:                                                                element = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain")
browser.execute_script()....but what would I put between the ()?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to do that. But using javascript didn't actually  fix this issue. I still get the same exact result.

Answer (score 0):

thinking that you excel has the data as shown below:

[image]

"**test1**" is for - First and Last name textbox

"**sample**" is for - Domain.com textbox

so with in the code you should change from

```
inputDomain.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i,2))
```

to

```
inputDomain.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i,1))
```

since you are extracting the data (sample) from the 0th row and 1st column not the 2nd column

for you reference please go through the code below in detail:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import xlrd

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
book = xlrd.open_workbook("path_to_excelfile\\sample.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
i=0
browser.get("https://www.voilanorbert.com")
inputName = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-name")))
inputName.click()
inputName.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
inputDomain = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-domain")))
inputDomain.click()
inputDomain.send_keys(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
norbertsearch = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
norbertsearch.click()
```

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the excel sheet, so you are wrong. And my data is in fact in the 1st and 3rd columns (aka 0th and 2nd columns). That is not the issue. Please read my question thoroughly...